# what will happen with the running jobs/requests in GCP after user account is disabled/suspended?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-cloud-iam

Let's assume Security Command Center (SCC) raised the following finding:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/login#account_disabled_hijacked

Can I assume that all currently running jobs/requests would be canceled/stopped?

Can I assume that all future jobs/requests would be impossible on behalf of a DISABLED/SUSPENDED user account ([I assume this state is relevant to Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33312?hl=en)?

How does it influence IAMs of suspended accounts https://cloud.google.com/identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the document on [Project Suspension guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-suspension-guidelines)

> when a Google Cloud user is consistently violating ToS or [Google Cloud Acceptable Use Policy](https://cloud.google.com/terms/aup) (AUP) through their projects, their access to Google Cloud may be suspended. When that happens, the developer will not be able to access their Cloud projects. They will continue to have access to other Google services like Gmail.
> When a Google Cloud account is suspended and the developer has at least one active project, they will get an email informing them about the project being suspended. The developer can go to the Console, fill out the form and reach out to Google to resolve the issue. See the [Policy Violations FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7002354?hl=en) for more information on appeal best practices in case of a Project resource suspension.

Once the IAM account is suspended then its jobs/request will stop automatically. Unless the account is activated the jobs/requests will not be in place.

To summarize the above ,Projects can be suspended due to ToS violations or and when that happens all the existing workloads are shut down and users lose access to the project. However, there is a notification sent to the project owner to fix the violation and after that you should be able to access your project again and start up your resources. It is possible that your account has a grace period in which you can still recover your data, but if you are over the grace period time your data might be unrecoverable.